# Error in program with structures and pointers (Structures, C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a structure , which contains three variables under the object list.-Names, registration nos, amount.

```
struct vendor
{
   int reg, amt;
   char add[30];
}list[10];
```

I have made a function to find the minimum amount(amt) ,using the referencing concept.

```
 int low(vendor *p, int n)
   {
int i;
min = (p->amt);
for(i =1;i<n;i++)
{
    if(min > *(p->amt))
    {
        min = *(p->amt);
    }
    p++;
}
return min;
 }
```

In the main I have included the syntax:

```
 low(list, n);
```

I am getting an error:

```
Invalid argument of unary '*' operator.
```

I have tried using the dot operator also  and is not working.
This is my first program in pointers in structs with functions.

Can you please point out the error in the code.

Thank You very much

Anupam

(Update) the full code:

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 struct vendor
     {
     int reg, amt;
     char add[30];
     }list[10];

int low(vendor *p, int n)
     {
       int i;
       min = (p->amt);
       for(i =1;i<n;i++)
     {
       if(min > (p->amt))
       {
        min = (p->amt);
       }
         p++;
     }
      return min;
    }


 int main()
{
   int i;
   int fa;
   int n,fr;
   cin >> n;
   for(i =0;i<n;i++)
    {
       cin >>list[i].reg>>list[i].add>>list[i].amt; 
      // Enter reg no. , address and amount.
       }

   low(list, n); // Calling function

    for(i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
       if(fr == list[i].amt)    
    // This is to check for position of least amount.
    // For printing the reg no. and address of least amt.
       {
          fa = i;
     }
 }

   cout << fr <<"\n" << fa <<endl;
   // print the reg no. and address of least amt.

  }
```

Errors:

```
   Overloaded function with no contextual type information.
   Invalid operands of types <unresolved overloaded function 
    Cannot resolve overloaded function
```

Comment: `p->amt` is of type `int`.  The expression `*(p->amt)` treats it as a pointer.   Instead of `*(p->amt)` simply write `p->amt` in your code.

Comment: I am getting errors. Please check updated question. Thank You.

Comment: You never declared a type for your `min` variable, so the compiler is assuming you are referencing the `min` function. Fix the error by declaring `min` properly.

Comment: I think you are right !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration for `min` is missing in `low()` function.

```
int min = (p->amt);
```

This should help you compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

`p` is a pointer to a vendor. `*p` is a vender. `p->amt` is an int.

So when you want the `amt` of an object that is pointed to by `p` you can do it in one of two ways: `p->amt` or `(*p).amt`

You fix your code by using `p->amt` or `(*p).amt`. `*p->amt` or `*(p->amt)` are invalid.

Comment: I am getting errors. Please check updated question. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

p is a object of vendor which type is pointer . "->" is used to use pointer object . So use p->amt .

you can also use (*p).amt .

Updated Answer :

decleration of min is missing .  please use this :

```
int min = p->amt ;
```

or use this :

```
int min = (*p).amt;
```

Comment: I am getting errors. Please check updated question. Thank You.